# Assign Unique Row Number based on pattern

Tags: sql, oracle, row-number

I have a table with the following fields

```
CourseID  Amount17 Amount15 Amount13
100152  3000    2400    0
100204  3000    2400    0
100066  3000    2400    0
100066  3000    2400    1800
100067  3000    2400    1800
100343  3000    2400    1800
100126  3000    2400    1800
100022  3000    3000    0
100344  3000    3000    0
100050  3000    3000    0
100078  3000    3000    0
```

I would like to group matching three amount columns in a list. My desired output

```
 CourseID  Amount17 Amount15 Amount13   CourseList
    100152  3000    2400    0            1
    100204  3000    2400    0            1
    100066  3000    2400    0            1
    100066  3000    2400    1800         2
    100067  3000    2400    1800         2
    100343  3000    2400    1800         2
    100126  3000    2400    1800         2
    100022  3000    3000    0            3
    100344  3000    3000    0            3
    100050  3000    3000    0            3
    100078  3000    3000    0            3
```

I have tried row_number over(order by ) but it does not seem to help. Tried using DenseRank but of no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just want `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (order by amount17, amount15, amount13) as courselist
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks. Am not sure why Dense_Rank wasnt working for me earlier.